How can i make hint text normal and input text bold?
I want to make hint text normal style and input text bold but when I change input text style bold it effects hint and hint became bold too. how can I solve that?
I want to change just input text. I've tried to set string as below ;
<string name="password_hint" style="@android:style/italic">Password</string>


but it didnt solved my problem.

To make the hint text normal and the input text bold in an EditText field, you can use the following steps:
    <style name="CustomEditTextStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:hint">@android:style/italic</item>
    </style>

This style sets the text style to bold, the text color to black, and the hint text style to italic.
Apply the custom text style to the EditText field:
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/password_hint"
        style="@style/CustomEditTextStyle" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

This code creates a TextInputLayout and sets the style attribute of the TextInputEditText to @style/CustomEditTextStyle.

this one didnt solve problem. the other solution that you write is the answer ive used it and solved the problem.

which other solution?

the one that includes SpannableString

ohh I tried but not work for me so I edited the Answer.  BTW it's solved the problem enjoy!
